# Symbolic link > not allowed or link target not accessible

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, dropbox

Ever since my hard-drive crashed, I've been backing up data to Dropbox.
But I've also been symlinking all my data folders to my Dropbox sub-folders.
After installing Apache on my Ubuntu desktop, I symlinked *username* to my Dropbox sub-folder.

> anjanesh@anjanesh-desktop:/var/www$ sudo ln -s ~/Dropbox/www anjanesh

But when I goto h-t-t-p://localhost/anjanesh/ I get

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /anjanesh/ on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I checked the error log :

> [Sun Aug 19 22:07:41 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link
>   not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/anjanesh

I don't seem to see anything wrong with the permissions.

```
anjanesh@anjanesh-desktop:/var/www$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 19 21:55 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Aug 19 11:19 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 Aug 19 21:55 anjanesh -> /home/anjanesh/Dropbox/www
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  177 Aug 19 11:20 index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   20 Aug 19 16:23 phpinfo.php
anjanesh@anjanesh-desktop:/var/www$
```

Any idea what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options) directive. Simply add `FollowSymLinks` to your virtual host configuration (or wherever applicable) and it should work.

The webserver usually runs as `www-run` or `www-data` or some other user. Make sure that user is allowed to access your data as well. So if you can, make your Dropbox web directory world-accesable and world-readable, or add the webserver user to your usergroup.